# Socket receiving data is not coming. I tested on hercules

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm sending data to Lector device.
Normally I received data from device when I sending on hercules.
Hercules is returning "sRA eExtIn1 0 0 0".
The below code has waiting line `stream.Read()` function.
How can I getting data from device?

```
string responseData = null;

using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("10.1.13.102", 2111))
{
   using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
   {
      byte[] sentData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<STX>sRN eExtIn1<ETX>");
      stream.Write(sentData, 0, sentData.Length);

      byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
      int bytes;
      if (client.Connected)
      {
         while ((bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
         {
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
            {
               responseData += (char)buffer[i];
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but if the docs for whatever you are doing tell you to send STX/ETX they most likely mean to send the bytes 0x2 / 0x3 not the string.

Comment: You're not waiting for the response. You're assuming that 1) the response will come instantly and 2) you'll receive the full response all at once. Neither assumption is valid. You need to do the read in a loop and keep reading until you have the full expected length. You'll probably want some timeout logic in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you're making, and the other answer is also making, is assuming that `stream.Read` won't return until it has read 32 bytes. That is incorrect.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(v=vs.110).aspx

> This method reads data into the buffer parameter and returns the
>   number of bytes successfully read. If no data is available for
>   reading, the Read method returns 0. The Read operation reads as much
>   data as is available, up to the number of bytes specified by the size
>   parameter.

It will return when there is no data available to read or 32 bytes have been read, ***whichever comes first***. So if, for example, the client is slow or the network very busy, the response may not have arrived yet when you call `stream.Read`. Consequently, there will be nothing to read so it will return 0 and you will exit, failing to read the data. In fact, you may have to call `stream.Read` any number of times to get the full 32 bytes if the network is very saturated and data is arriving a few bytes at a time (not likely with such a small packet, but you have to code it that way).

So your code needs to look like this (note the additional while loop):

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("10.1.13.102", 2111))
{
   using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
   {
      byte[] sentData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<STX>sRN eExtIn1<ETX>");
      stream.Write(sentData, 0, sentData.Length);

      byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
      int bytes;
      if (client.Connected)
      {
         int bytesRead = 0;
         while (bytesRead < buffer.Length)
         {
             while ((bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
             {
                for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
                {
                   responseData += (char)buffer[i];
                }
                bytesRead += bytes;
             }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody.
I found solution of my question.
 and  tags should be describe as bytes. Like below.

```
  byte[] byt = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("sRN DItype");
                    stream.Write(STX, 0 , 1);
                    stream.Write(byt, 0, byt.Length);
                    stream.Write(ETX, 0, 1);
                        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```